# cloud function instance seems to upgrade automatically the memory if needed (gen 2)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm using cloud function (gen 2). The cloud function is running in python 3.10. During the execution of the cloud function there are a lot of heavy files that are cached in memory.

It happens quite often that there is a message error of this type:
`Memory limit of 1907 MiB exceeded with 2059 MiB used. Consider increasing the memory limit, see https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/configuring/memory`

Most of the time, after this message the cloud function is still running (but sometimes the cloud function fails few seconds after).

Does it mean there is an automatic upgrade of the memory ?

I put some logs with the memory used during the execution with `psutil.virtual_memory()`.

So here is an example:

1. memory log before memory alert:

`INFO:svmem(total=2147483648, available=498733056, percent=76.8, used=1433911296, free=498733056, active=1547333632, inactive=101404672, buffers=0, cached=214839296, shared=12029952, slab=0)`

2. message of error:

`Memory limit of 1907 MiB exceeded with 2059 MiB used. Consider increasing the memory limit, see https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/configuring/memory`

3. after the memory error:

`INFO:svmem(total=3221225472, available=1300992000, percent=59.6, used=1705369600, free=1300992000, active=1818804224, inactive=101416960, buffers=0, cached=214863872, shared=12029952, slab=0)`

What I see here is the total memory has been increased more than 1 GB. Am I correct, is the library also accurate ?
Is there really an upgrade of the memory ?
Have you observed that also ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not correct. Cloud Functions use only the memory allowed. When you have a memory error message, it means your Cloud Functions instance has crashed, and a new instance is spawned.

Because the instance is fresh, all the memory is swapped, and you have more free space.

About the "available memory", you can't rely on your own analysis tool. The environment is virtualized and sandboxed. You will have the same crash issue because of 2gb of memory are full even if the total with your tool displays  3Gb.